# Custom comment flag left unhandled when comment is auto-deleted

Tags: support, comments, moderator-tools, comment-flags

I just spotted this peculiarity:

[image]

<sup>(The name is that of the comment author; the name of the flag author is not shown.)</sup>

Notice the red background, which indicates that the comment is deleted.

The question has been closed as a duplicate, so naturally the comment, having been inserted along with the close vote, was deleted in the process of closing the question.

The flag was raised at around the same time the comment was posted, but the question was closed much later, so it doesn't seem to be caused by a race condition or anything. It looks like comment flags are quite simply left unhandled when auto-deleting comments.

Is this intentional?